# possible unhandled promise rejection_Expo Image Picker

Tags: expo, react-native-image-picker

I want to use Expo Image Picker, but I'm getting the following error.

'Console Warning : possible unhandled promise rejection (id : 0)'.

I already installed 'expo-image-picker'.

Here's the promise code, I don't see what's wrong here, any ideas?

```
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button,Image } from 'react-native';
    import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
    import Constants from 'expo-constants';

    export default function App() {
      const [image,setImage] = useState(null);
      useEffect(async () => {
        if(Platform.OS !== 'web'){
          const {status} = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted'){
            alert('Permisson denied!')
          }
        }
      }, []);

      const PickImage = async() => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes : ImagePicker.mediaTypesOptions.All,
          allowsEditing:true,
          aspect:[4,3],
          quality:1
        })
        console.log(result)
        if(!result.cancelled ){
          setImage(result.uri)
        }
      }

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title = "Choose Image" onPress = {PickImage}/> 
          {image &&  <Image source={{uri:image}} style = {{
            width : 200,
            height:200
          }}/>}
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    } 

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning properties to mediatypes is incorrect.
Correction: `mediaTypes:ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,`